# Where can I buy a deck of personalized cards?

Tags: playing-cards, custom-game-pieces

I want to design my own cards, backside and frontside (on the frontside only the pictures for jack, queen, king, and ace). One of the biggest problems is that I only want two decks,  not thousands of them. It's a birthday gift for my girlfriend.

Where can I buy bridge cards that I can personalize and how much would it cost (including shipping to the Netherlands)?

Are there other ways to print a low quantity of customized cards?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try makeplayingcards.com

Comment: you can also try Cartamundi(http://www.cartamundi.com/). It's a card printing company located in Belgium, Turnhout(at lease one of the printing locations), so shipping will be fairly cheap I guess. I've never ordered anything there, so can't give any feedback. But they print MTG cards, so they should be good :)

Comment: @Novarg I think Cartamundi is only for really large orders, isn't it? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MichaSprengers I don't know. As I said, *I've never ordered anything there* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had great [experiences](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/2349511/ikegami) with [Printer's Studio](http://www.printerstudio.com/).

- You can have anything from a custom back on standard playing card fronts to completely custom fronts and backs that are different for each card.
- Good interface for building these decks.
- While the images you submit must have a bleed, the jobs I submitted were spot-on.
- No minimum order size (though you get discounts for buying in bulk).

Tips:

- Don't order without a coupon. You can always get a deal. At the very least, sign up for the mailing list to get $10 off, which will cover the shipping. (The best I've seen was early in the new year where they had a deal for 15% off and free shipping!)
- You might be able to save a buck by going to the [Canadian portal](http://www.printerstudio.ca/). The prices of items are the same as the US portal, but the Canadian dollar is weaker. The company is based in Hong Kong.
- If you want cards that are perfectly flat, go for the linen instead of the standard. Both types are high quality. (I have no experience with their "plastic" cards.)

Comment: I've ordered more "standard" cards from them. While the first ones I got were a little bowed, the new ones lie flat like the linen cards I got earlier.